# Cannot upgrade WindowsAzure.Storage to 8.1.1

Tags: azure-webjobs

I have a solution that contains 2 webjobs projects in it.  The solution was developed on one machine using VS2015.  I recently upgraded the solution to VS2017.  Both of the webjobs projects have WindowsAzure.Storage v8.1.1 installed on it.  There are also 2 other projects in the solution that have WindowsAzure.Storage v8.1.1 installed.

This solution is saved in TFS.

On a second, freshly built machine with VS2017 installed, I fetched a copy of the solution from TFS.  Many of the references from Nuget were not found.  After some time, I was able to refresh all the Nuget package for the solution.  All but WindowsAzure.Storage v8.1.1.  The only version that will install on the new machine is v7.2.1.  When I try to upgrade the solution to v8.2.1 it simply fails and rolls back.  I'm not getting any indication what it's failing on.

The other 2 projects that are using v8.1.1 install fine on both machines.  It seems that the issue is only on the webjobs projects.

The 2 webjobs projects are targeting different platforms.  One is targeting 4.6.1 and the other is targeting 4.5.2.

I've been working on this for several days now.  Since I don't seem to be any closer to solving the problem, I decided to ask the question here.

I'm thinking I'm missing an install of something, but I'm not getting enough feedback from Nuget to let me know what I'm missing.

Comment: Could you please post some details information about the update failed message?You could find it in the Nuget Package Console. You could open it by below ways: Tools--> Nuget Package Manager -->Nuget Package Console.Besides, I suggest you could check the packages.config file in the webjob solution to make sure the storage version is 8.1.1. You could also try to uninstall all the package, clear all nuget cache(Tools --> Nuget Package Manager --> Package Manager Settings) and reinstall all the package.

Comment: Here is some of the package manager output.  The only piece in here that seems to give any indication of the problem are the references to the prerequisites for v8.1.1. which are all met. This same problem happens on any new Webjobs project I try to create.

Package 'WindowsAzure.Storage.8.1.1' already exists in folder Install failed. Rolling back...
Package 'WindowsAzure.Storage.8.1.1 : Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core [1.0.0, ), Microsoft.Data.OData [5.8.2, ), Microsoft.Data.Services.Client [5.8.2, ), Newtonsoft.Json [6.0.8, )' does not exist in project 'Cohorts.Castle.WebJobs'

Comment: AFAIK, the nugget package will roll back is happened when other package has used the low version of its dependencies.
For example: if one package need Json package is 6.8, but another package(last version) need the package >=7.2. If you update the second package, it will roll back.So I suggest you could firstly check your package.config file between VS2015 and VS2017 and check the package's dependencies.Besides, I couldn’t understand why your new webjob project couldn’t install the new storage package. Could you please post the details steps about how you create it and your VS2017 version.

Comment: I also can't understand why the new webjob project couldn't install the new storage package.  I can install the most current version of every supporting package separately, but v8.1.1 simply fails.  I get the same behaviour on a new webjobs project.  I have 2 theories, but I can't prove either.  1. It might have something to do with ReSharper having installed packages differently on my older machine.  2. I might have installed other software outside of VS on my older machine.  Neither makes much sense, but I'm running out of rational reasons why it's failing.